# Input Validation for PhoneTextBox in windows phone app 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i'm developing a windows phone application.in my application i want to make input validation for textbox.i'm using

```
windows phone toolkit :PhoneTextBox
```

need to alert a Message when user fail to fill the textbox after click the submit button.is there any way to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button_click` event, add a condition,

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneTextBox.Text))
{
    //your action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button`'s event handler make sure you have:

```
your eventhandler(){
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text)) //here "tb" is the textbox name, in case of that give your textbox's name.
 {
 MessageBox.Show("TextBox is empty");
 }  
}
```

Or else try using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in order to check whether the string is empty.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name)) //give the name of your textbox.Text
{
//Handled
}
```

Reference: [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On `Button_click` you have to check. Try following code.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(YourTextBox.Text)) // it check it text box is null or empty
{
  //your action here
}
```